# Stop Rolify from automatically creating roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rolify

I've just started using Rolify and want to define the roles statically in the roles table, I've read the GitHub documentation and searched online.

Bard AI suggested that the following would do what I need ( rolify skip_create_role: true ) but I found no documentation on this and it doesn't seem to work.

I'm using the ( config.remove_role_if_empty = false ) in the config/initializers/rolify.rb file which fixes the deleting of roles if they are not in use, however I cannot find a way to stop roles from being automatically created.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  rolify skip_create_role: true
  
  validates etc, etc 
end

Rolify.configure do |config|
  # By default ORM adapter is ActiveRecord. uncomment to use mongoid
  # config.use_mongoid

  # Dynamic shortcuts for User class (user.is_admin? like methods). Default is: false
  # config.use_dynamic_shortcuts

  # Configuration to remove roles from database once the last resource is removed. Default is: true
  config.remove_role_if_empty = false

end
```

Comment: That's topflight AI hallucination -- looking through the github repo there are only three config attributes remove_role_if_empty, orm and dyanmic_shortcuts. You're best bet is to add something in a before_add callback.  Though you seem to be fighting rolify's intended purpose which is to automatically add roles.

Comment: LOL, that's the conclusion I came to. I must admit the way rolify works here does not feel intuitive to me, it has a create_role which does what I’d expect, so the add_role which I’d prefer to be renamed assign_role should assign the role to the user etc. 

Either way I was hoping that there would be a similar option to `config.remove_role_if_empty` but to stop the automatic creation of roles, maybe I’ll ask them to add a `config.skip_create_role` and keep bard happy :)

Comment: The Rolify gem is designed to create roles dynamically, and there's no built-in feature to prevent the automatic creation of new roles when using methods like add_role. The skip_create_role: true option you mentioned is not part of the Rolify gem's standard configuration, as of my last update.

If you want to restrict role creation to a predefined set of roles and prevent dynamic role creation, you'll have to implement this behavior manually in your application logic.

Comment: If you really want this functionality it does not seems like it would be too overwhelming to implement as a monkey patch, just need to understand what you want to have happen when a "new role" would be added. If you can provide some form of example as to how you see this functioning maybe we can help propose some solutions.